# Difference between the following code C/C++ code

Tags: c++, c

The first one is :

```
if(n--)
{
 //do something
}
```

The second is :

```
if(n)
{
//do something
n--;
}
```

I'm not able to understand the difference between these two pieces of code.
Both are giving different outputs.

Comment: If `n` is 0, then in first case after `if` block `n` will become -1 but in second case it will not change

Comment: `if(n--)` decrements `n` essentially while still in the `if`, meaning it will already have been decremented before `do something`

Comment: @kuro Correct me if I'm wrong but  if n is 0, none of the statements will execute.

Comment: The statements in the `if` block will not execute in that case

Comment: let say, n=1. For the first `if`, it is true and it will decrement 1 to 0 immediately. so if you print at the beginning of  `if` you will see n=0. For the 2nd `if`,  you will see n=1, then n-- will decrement it.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to learn two language features at once but it's probably easier to learn them in isolation... first learn what `n--` does and the difference between `n--` and `--n`  (post decrement vs pre decrement).  Then learn what an `if` statement does.  Then when you see the two things used together there should be little confusion.

Comment: Example, if n=1, in the first one, n will become 0 before do something, but in the second, n will become 0 after do something

Answer (score 3):

The first one always subtracts 1 from `n` no matter what, when the condition of the if statement gets evaluated.

The second one will only subtract 1 from `n` if `n` was non-zero at the beginning of the code block, because the `n--` is inside the first block of the if statement, and that block only runs if the condition is non-zero.

Both pieces of code are similar in that they will only execute the "do something" if `n` was non-zero at beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, n is the value substracted during "do something",
the second one, n is the previous value during "do something".

Answer (score 0):

let say, n=1. For the first if, it is true and it will decrement 1 to 0 immediately. so if you print at the beginning of  if you will see n=0. For the 2nd if, you will see n=1, then n-- will decrement it.

Run the below code, you will get it.

The first one is :

```
if(n--)
{
  printf("%d\n",n);
 //do something
}
```

The second is :

```
if(n)
{
 printf("%d\n",n);
//do something
n--;
}
```